# how can i sql pivot this select?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

```
SELECT sc.CID,sc.CodeName as OverviewText,scRAG.CodeName as RAGStatusText 
FROM StatusCode sc
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjectOverview po ON sc.CID = po.ProjectOverviewCID AND po.ProjectId = 180
    LEFT OUTER JOIN StatusCode scRAG ON po.RAGStatusCID = scRAG.CID
WHERE sc.SCID = 18
```

the above code result sin this:

```
CID OverviewText    RAGStatusText
153 Cost            Green
154 Requirements    Yellow
155 Schedule    NULL
156 Technical   NULL
157 Testing         NULL
```

I want it to return one record with 10 fields:

Cost, Green, Requirements,  Yellow,
    Schedule,   NULL,
    Technical,  NULL,
    Testing,            NULL

Can i pivot on cid?

Comment: This is [at least your 6th pivot question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A352157+pivot) as far as I can see. What have you tried so far?

Comment: 2nd. the rest are variations or other questions that have a pivot in the code.

Comment: Will the table that contains the CID column have any more rows added to it, in the future, or is it for all intensive purposes readonly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having seperate columns, could you live with one column? Like this?

```
create table #t1([CID] int
,[OverviewText] varchar(12)
,[RAGStatusText] varchar(6))

insert #t1 values (153,'Cost','Green')
insert #t1 values (154,'Requirements','Yellow')
insert #t1 values (155,'Schedule',NULL)
insert #t1 values (156,'Technical',NULL)
insert #t1 values (157,'Testing',NULL)

select StringToSpit = stuff((select 
 [text()]=','+[OverviewText]+','+isnull([RAGStatusText],'NULL')
from #t1 
for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```